# How refresh UIVIewController to NSOperationQueue

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, nsoperationqueue

I have a view where I show an UIImageView which complimentary internet, I use to bring data NSXMLparser which are loaded correctly, the problem was that I use to make the parser NSOperationQueue background so then I refresh the image in my main view. image which form no refresh them in any way

I leave here the code below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [Base64 initialize];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                            selector:@selector(loadDataWithOperation)
                                                                              object:nil];
    [queue addOperation:operation];
    [operation release];
}

- (void) loadDataWithOperation {
    getData=NO;
    NSURL *url1 =  [ NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:xmlData];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showImage)withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

-(void)showImage
{
    NSArray *imagen =[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:xml];
    NSString *hola1 =[[imagen objectAtIndex:5]objectForKey:@"imagen"];
    NSData * dataa = [Base64 decode:hola1];
    img = [UIImage imageWithData:dataa];
    self.images.image = img;
    [images setImage:img];
    [img release];
}
```

What am I doing wrong? appreciate your help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything obvious (though obviously we don't see the building of the `xml` array nor do we know precisely what the XML itself looks like). You should `NSLog` (or set a breakpoint and manually inspect) the `xml` as well as `hola1` and `dataa` results in `showImage`, to identify at precisely what's going on at each step.

There are two possible problems with background operations and downloading XML. Neither of these seem applicable here, but I'll mention it just in case:

1. But there's nothing that would prevent the downloading and parsing of your XML like you have demonstrated here. If you were using `NSURLConnection` to download the XML (perhaps you simplified it here for the purposes of demonstration), there are issues in using `NSURLConnection` in a background queue. But if you use `dataWithContentsOfURL` (or better, `NSXMLParser` method `initWithContentsOfURL`) that wouldn't be an issue.
2. It looks like you're downloading a single XML, but if you were downloading multiple XML sources simultaneously, you should appreciate that many servers impose a limit as to how many concurrent connections they'll allow from a single client. You can use `NSOperationQueue` property `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to mitigate that problem. Four is a typical value.

---

Unrelated, but there are a couple of minor memory management things you might want to look at:

- if you already have `xml` you don't need to create a new `imagen`;
- you should probably `release` the `queue` object after adding the `operation`, or if you need to keep it around to reuse it, you should make it a class property or instance variable;
- you could get rid of `operation` completely if you did:

  ```
  [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
      [self loadDataWithOperation];
  }];
  ```
- you should `release` the `parser` object when you're done with it;
- if you keep `imagen` in your code you should also `release` it when done; and
- you should not `release` the `img` object since `imageWithData` returns an `autorelease` object

The routine memory management stuff probably would be pointed out to you if you did a static analysis (choose "Analyze" from the "Product" menu).

One final observation:

- I notice that you have:

  ```
  NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1];
  NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:xmlData];
  ```

  Clearly that `xmlData` is not necessary because you could have also just have done:

  ```
  NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url1];
  ```

Comment: thanks for your reply, XML brings the image properly if I put Self.View = img variable which contains the image, I load the image in full view, the problem is when I try to load the image UIImageView me or make a refresh so that it can display the correct image. sii run the same code on the main thread the UIImage view sii me load properly.

Comment: @LaurxsSepeda I'm afraid I don't understand you, but my counsel would be the same. Either set breakpoints and single step through your code, line-by-line, to figure out at which line are you not getting the result you want, or put in a ton of NSLog statements, one after each assignment of a variable, to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @LaurxsSepeda By the way, there are two possible issues in background downloading of XML that I mention in my revised answer. On the basis of your question, these seem unlikely, but it's something to consider.

Comment: Thank you very much pro your answers, @ Rob I followed your advice and I still do not get the desired results, place many NSLog and when loading the same image to UIImageView asiganada if the problem is that the refresh is not performed in view of simulator.

Comment: @LaurxsSepeda I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you're trying to say. Worse, I'm not at all sure as to which `NSLog` statement reported a value different than what you expected. Bottom line just don't have enough here to diagnose your problem. You have to be very specific about what the `NSLog` was supposed to generate, what it did generate, and then show us the code that set the property/variable for which you logged and received the unexpected value. Maybe update your original question, but be more specific?